# Best way to clean up stale workspaces and shelvesets

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

I know that there is Tf destroy and other tools out there to clean up stale workspaces, but I'm studying for the MS 496 exam. Which tool is recognized and preferred to clean up workspaces and shelvesets according to the exam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an actual day-to-day user of TFS, I'd agree that the TFS Sidekicks is a great complement to the Microsoft-provided tooling. However, that's not going to be an option on the 70-496 exam. `tf.exe` is going to be the tool of choice for managing other users' workspaces.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for both answers, Daniel. Tf.exe pointed me to a good starting point for other sections as well!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the exam but Team Foundation Server Sidekicks by Attrice Corporation is the best http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

Comment: The URL is broken.